# Disable Soft Deleteable filter for hard delete record doesn't work

Tags: symfony, testing, doctrine-orm, phpunit, functional-testing

I'm trying to disable "Soft Deleteable" filter during functional testing and I do it as follow:

First option: tried to disable at `tearDown()` in my test:

```
protected function tearDown() {
    parent::tearDown();

    $entityUser = $this->em->getRepository("UserSecurityBundle:User")->find($this->user->getUser()->getId());

    $filter = $this->em->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');

    $this->em->remove($entityUser);
    $this->em->flush();
    $this->em->close();
}
```

**Didn't work.**

Second option: make a doctrine_test.yml and import in config_test.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
    - { resource: doctrine_test.yml }
    - { resource: security_test.yml }
```

In this case I remove the `doctrine.yml` and include in `config_prod.yml`.

**Didn't work.**

This is how my `doctrine_test.yml` section look like:

```
filters:
    softdeleteable:
        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
        enabled: false
```

Third option: disable the filter in `setUp()`:

```
public function setUp() {
    static::$kernel = static::createKernel();
    static::$kernel->boot();
    $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

    $fixture = new LoadFeeData();
    $fixture->load($this->em);

    $this->em->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');
    $this->user = $this->createUser();

    parent::setUp();
}
```

**Didn't work.**

Any advice? Solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after some research, after doing more test I found the solution, see below:

```
protected function tearDown() {
    parent::tearDown();

    $entityAccount = $this->em->getRepository("UserSecurityBundle:Account")->find(array("id" => $this->user->getId(), "user" => $this->user->getUser()->getId()));
    $entityUser = $entityAccount->getUser();

    $entityCompanyHasWtax = $this->em->getRepository("ApprovalBundle:CompanyHasWtax")->findOneBy(array("company" => $this->company, "wtax" => $this->fee, "user" => $this->user->getUser()->getId()));

    foreach ($this->em->getEventManager()->getListeners() as $eventName => $listeners) {
        foreach ($listeners as $listener) {
            if ($listener instanceof \Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener) {
                $this->em->getEventManager()->removeEventListener($eventName, $listener);
            }
        }
    }

    $this->em->remove($entityCompanyHasWtax);
    $this->em->remove($entityAccount);
    $this->em->remove($entityUser);

    $this->em->flush();
    $this->em->close();
}
```

Aparently Doctrine has a bug since disabling the filter in this way:

```
$this->em->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');
```

Doesn't work, good look for others

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. In my understanding, `$this->em->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');` only disables the filter for retrieving soft-deleted entities. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35459837/2564552

Answer (score -1):

Although this question is a bit old maybe it is useful to someone:

Creating your own event listener might be a better solution:

```
class SoftDeleteableListener extends BaseSoftDeleteableListener
{

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function onFlush(EventArgs $args)
{
    $ea = $this->getEventAdapter($args);
    $om = $ea->getObjectManager();
    //return from event listener if you disabled filter: $em->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');
    if (!$om->getFilters()->isEnabled('softdeleteable')) {
        return;
    }

    parent::onFlush($args);
}

}
```

And adding in your config:

```
gedmo.listener.softdeleteable:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\SoftDeleteableListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
    calls:
        - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]
```

source: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/1175