# How to disable soft delete (Soft-deleteable) filter for doctrine in symfony

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, soft-delete

Installing and using SoftDeleteable behavior extension for Doctrine 2 is quite easy. The problem usually is trying to disable it for some code part and enabling again. You may want to do this to:

1. load entity that is soft-deleted
2. remove entity from database entirely bypassing soft-delete filter

So how to disable it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## 1. How to load soft-deleted entity

As per the documentation, disable filter for entity manager:

```
$em->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');
$object = $em->find('AppBundle:Object', 1); // soft-deleted entity will be loaded
```

To enable soft-delete again:

```
$em->getFilters()->enable('softdeleteable');
```

Note: `$em->clear();` may be required before this line, if entity was already loaded with disabled soft-delete filter.

## 2. How to remove entity from database entirely

Even though it is not mentioned in documentation, the first solution does not work if you need to remove entity and bypass soft-delete filter. Filter needs to be removed from entity manager's event listeners:

```
// initiate an array for the removed listeners
$originalEventListeners = [];

// cycle through all registered event listeners
foreach ($em->getEventManager()->getListeners() as $eventName => $listeners) {
    foreach ($listeners as $listener) {
        if ($listener instanceof \Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener) {

            // store the event listener, that gets removed
            $originalEventListeners[$eventName] = $listener;

            // remove the SoftDeletableSubscriber event listener
            $em->getEventManager()->removeEventListener($eventName, $listener);
        }
    }
}

// remove the entity
$em->remove($object);
$em->flush($object); // or $em->flush();

// re-add the removed listener back to the event-manager
foreach ($originalEventListeners as $eventName => $listener) {
    $em->getEventManager()->addEventListener($eventName, $listener);
}
```

References:

- https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md
- [Force delete doctrine entity when using SoftDeletable by KnpLabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926836/force-delete-doctrine-entity-when-using-softdeletable-by-knplabs/35459837#35459837)
- [Disable Soft Deleteable filter for hard delete record doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812675/disable-soft-deleteable-filter-for-hard-delete-record-doesnt-work/22838467#22838467)

Comment: The filter is just a doctrine query so it has no real connection to the flushing process. A far easier way to hard delete would be to to run the the `$em->remove($object); $em->flush($object);` twice. The first flush would set the `deletedAt` to now. The second would recognise that the `deletedAt` has been set previously and will ignore actually delete - ass you can see here https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/SoftDeleteable/SoftDeleteableListener.php#L63-L71.

Comment: @qooplmao I tried this with latest tag (2.4.13) and it does not work. Maybe only with master branch now.

Comment: @qooplmao Your method works perfectly well. I think you should post it as an answer, as I ended up ignoring it the first time. Aurelijus' answer is informative, but ultimately unnecessary. I tried it with v2.5.5.

Comment: If it doesn't work try  "soft-deleteable" instead of "softdeleteable". So it should be: `$em->getFilters()->disable('soft-deleteable');`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a service to disable and reenable the soft delete filter behaviour:

```
<?php

namespace App\Util;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener;

class SoftDeleteFilter
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    const EVENT_NAME = 'onFlush';

    /**
     * @var object
     */
    private $originalEventListener;

    /**
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function removeSoftDeleteFilter(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        foreach ($em->getEventManager()->getListeners() as $eventName => $listeners) {
            foreach ($listeners as $listener) {
                if ($listener instanceof SoftDeleteableListener) {
                    if ($eventName === self::EVENT_NAME) {
                        $this->originalEventListener = $listener;
                        $em->getEventManager()->removeEventListener($eventName, $listener);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function undoRemoveSoftDeleteFilter(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        if (empty($this->originalEventListener)) {
            throw new \Exception('can not undo remove, soft delete listener was not removed');
        }
        // re-add the removed listener back to the event-manager
        $em->getEventManager()->addEventListener(self::EVENT_NAME, $this->originalEventListener);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
$this->softDeleteFilter->removeSoftDeleteFilter($this->entityManager);
$this->entityManager->remove($entity);
$this->entityManager->flush();
$this->softDeleteFilter->undoRemoveSoftDeleteFilter($this->entityManager);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a small reminder.

When you want to hard delete entity with Gedmo Softdeletable you have to have `hardDelete=true` in the respective annotation, see:

`@Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false, hardDelete=true)`

EDIT: `hardDelete=true` is true by default

With this, you dont have to disable the listener/filter. If you have `hardDelete=false`, the double remove suggested above will not work.

Source:

- https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/softdeleteable.md

Comment: However `hardDelete` is true by default.

Answer (score -3):

As in a [former comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198357/how-to-disable-soft-delete-soft-deleteable-filter-for-doctrine-in-symfony#comment63821162_38198358) by [qooplmao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1791606/qooplmao) posted: A simple and working solution is:

```
// Remove an entity entirely from the DB (skip soft delete)
$this->entityManager->remove($entity);
$this->entityManager->flush();
// Just run it a second time :-)
$this->entityManager->remove($entity);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

Just posted it again to give it a little bot more visibility as it works like a charme...