# Symfony2, KnpLabs DoctrineBehaviors: How do I truly delete a softdeletable entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, soft-delete

Is there a way to override the softdeletable behaviour with [KNPLabs DoctrineBehaviors](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors) from a controller?

In my action, I would like to be able to momentarily "disable" the softdeletable behaviour so I can **truly remove my entity from the database** instead of just setting the `deletedAt` field.

Comment: Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22812675/disable-soft-deleteable-filter-for-hard-delete-record-doesnt-work

Comment: @spackmat Your link refers to a different bundle (Gedmo/SoftDeleteable), wihile my answer refers to KnpLabs DoctrineBehaviors SoftDeletable.

Comment: Yes, but this also works the same with KnpLabs DoctrineBehaviors SoftDeletable (I implemented it this way in my project). But your own answer is better, so nervermind. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nifr](https://github.com/nifr) kindly gave me an answer on Github:
https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/issues/294#issuecomment-190310921:

> Quick 'n dirty:
>
> ```
> $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default');
> $eventManager = $entityManager->getEventManager();
>
> // remove the softdeletable subscriber
> $subscriber = $this->get('knp.doctrine_behaviors.softdeletable_subscriber');
> $eventManager->removeEventListener($subscriber->getSubscribedEvents(), $subscriber);
>
> // remove entity while the subscriber is removed
> $entityManager->remove($entity);
> $entityManager->flush();
>
> // add back the subscriber
> $eventManager->addEventSubscriber($subscriber);
> ```

**PROBLEM**
This triggers the error "`you have requested a non-existent service`", because the service is not public.

To resolve this issue, according to nifr, 2 possible solutions:

1) define your controller itself as a service and inject the subscriber-service explicitly
2) create a factory-service that would return the subscriber service and call that one in your controller

Comment: This solution doesn't work (anymore?) as described in your linked source. The `knp.doctrine_behaviors.softdeletable_subscriber` service isn't public and can't be accessed without some extra work. So for now it leads to this error: 'You have requested a non-existent service "knp.doctrine_behaviors.softdeletable_subscriber".'

Comment: @spackmat You're right. That's what I said to nifr. In my original answer, I only put the link to the github thread, so one could read everything, but it's been edited. I'll change it.